# javascript - unable to call function from embedded SWF

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I created an AS3 script with a function

```
public function sayHello():String
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

I have also registered the callback as follows

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sayHello", sayHello);
```

In my javascript, I have embedded the SWF file as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF("HelloWorld.swf", "HelloWorld", "1", "1", "9.0.0");
</script>
```

But when I try to call the `sayHello` method as follows

```
document.getElementById("HelloWorld").sayHello();
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sayHello' of undefined`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the swf isn't loaded yet then `document.getElementById("HelloWorld")` will return undefined hence your error. You can try if this is the case by calling that couple seconds later.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("HelloWorld").sayHello();
},5000);
```

I would also put that code inside a function that is called on body onload event ie.

```
...
<head>
<script>

function onload() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("HelloWorld").sayHello();
    },5000);
}

</script>
...
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
...
</body>
```